Is there any solution like prettier in vs code for ECL HPCC?
I am looking for a way that will solve indentation issue. There are hundred lines of code and I want to prettify it.
Please guide if you have found any solution in your expertise.
Tried ECL Language forum. But dint work for me.

Why don't you use the built-in formatter Shift + Alt + F

Gives error :There is no formatter for 'ecl' installed.

Unfortunately, there is no prettier capability. Not really clear what you mean when you say, "not up to the mark". If you can be a little more specific, we have an issue tracker available where you can submit your suggestions. We also have an open source ECL IDE that has many formatting options (Windows only).

Apologies. That was a typo. By support I mean forum. link

Thanks @Bob. Comment from you means a lot. Watched all of your ECL Training videos. I am working on a way to build a custom code formatter and put all the formatting requirements in it. Please reflect on it if you have tried and tested this.

Thanks Yomane, visit  https://github.com/hpcc-systems/vscode-ecl/discussions which is a discussion are related to the ECL Extension (and the developers monitor).

Thanks Bob. Will use the forum for further discussion.
